# Scanf a char using %d

Tags: c, format, scanf

I have a specific example below, which works perfectly fine if integers are inputted (see output1), when I try to scan a char using %d specifier in scanf function call I get the output2 below.

So, my question is if input a char I hope the type specifier should convert it to an equivalent int value, if not a junk value, even in the either case it should print/segfault. But, here I'm getting continuous prints which I feel is wrong as scanf is getting bypassed every single time. I'm pretty unsure what's happening in the background and would like to know the same.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

   int a;

   while (1){
       printf("enter a number:");
       scanf("%d", &a);
       printf("entered number is %d\n", a);
   }

return 0;
}
```

**Output1**:

```
>     enter a number:1
>     entered number is 1
>     enter a number:
>     3
>     entered number is 3
>     enter a number:4
>     entered number is 4
>     enter a number:5
>     entered number is 5 enter a number:
```

**Output2**: for input a

```
>     enter a number:entered number is 32767
>     enter a number:entered number is 32767
>     enter a number:entered number is 32767
>     enter a number:entered number is 32767
>     enter a number:entered number is 32767
>     enter a number:entered number is 32767
>     enter a number:entered number is 32767
>     enter a number:entered number is 32767
>     enter a number:entered number is 32767
```

PS: I know this is a stupid question of asking what happens in an invalid case where a type specifier unintended (%d in this case) is used for different type, but I would like to know what happens in the background, if any. Thanks

Comment: Short story: If the input doesn't match the format then [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) returns early (check what the call returns! always!) leaving the input still in the buffer.

Comment: In the background (actually in right in front of you, but you ignore it) scanf tells you that it did not successfully read an integer. The return value carries that information.

Comment: `"%d"` expects numeric input like `(white-spaces)(sign)[digits]`.  If the user does not type that, nothing is read and text remains in `stdin` for the next input function - With your code, bad input leads to an endless loop as the offending text is never consumed.

Comment: %d will not read characters. You will need to use %c for that.

Comment: "if input a char" ---> Tip: By "char", I think you mean letters. In C, a `char` is a type of 1 byte.  `scanf()` does not read char, but _characters_.  Some _characters_ are letters, digits, punctuation, controls, etc.

Comment: So you intentionally invoke undefined behaviour and wonder why you see undefined behaviour … Good question, you are only the 100000th asker. Didn't the other 99999 provide the exact answer you want to see?

Comment: *I would like to know what happens in the background* - As for any undefined behavior - the implementation does not bother to handle these cases, so you get some residuals and junk from the other processing.

Comment: "I hope the type specifier should convert it to an equivalent int value."  But as The Man in Black said, "Prepare to be disappointed."  When you have `int x = 'c';`, then yes, C will automatically convert the character to an integer for you.  But that's in an an ordinary assignment.  When you 're using `scanf` and a `%d` format, on the other hand, such a conversion is simply *not* performed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may check scanf as [@Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44660548/scanf-a-char-using-d#comment76306518_44660548). You may compare the count arguments succesfully filled (Thanks to [@chux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44660548/scanf-a-char-using-d/44660768?noredirect=1#comment76307085_44660768))

In your case, scanf didn't find any integer value, reached the end of the input and returned EOF, keeping the `a` variable untouched.

On failure it'll return EOF (read http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/#return).

```
if(scanf("%d", &a) == 1) //Check if exactly one parameter was read. 
    printf("entered number is %d\n", a);
```

For characters, you better use `getch()` or at least, ask for `"%c"` on scanf:

```
if(scanf("%c", &a) == 1)
    printf("entered key was %d\n", a);
```

The "junk" value you recieve is what was in your program memory, because `a` is not initialized.

Comment: Hey chux, how did you link to programmer dude comment?

Comment: Note: `if(scanf("%d", &a) == 1)` has the advantage with more complex formats like `scanf("xyz%d", &a)` which may return 0,1,EOF.

Comment: Right click on comment's timestamp to get a link.  BTW, looks like you have been visited by a serial down-voter.

Comment: Oh, thanks @chux, I never did check parameter count. I'll update my answer.

Comment: "returned EOF, keeping the a variable untouched." may be technically wrong.  Should a rare input error occur (e.g. broken KB wire), `EOF` is returned and the state of `a` may be unknown.  I have not found the C spec on that, but in general, best not to count on the state of `a` when an input error occurs.