# Storing characters into integer variables with %d and %c and vice versa

Tags: c

I have no problem understanding the following, because in both cases they're really stored as `int` types.

```
int a; // combination 1
scanf("%d", &a); // suppose input is 65
printf("%c", a); // prints 'A'
printf("%d", a); // prints 65

char a; // combination 2
scanf("%c", &a); // suppose input is 'A'
printf("%c", a); // prints 'A'
printf("%d", a); // prints 65
```

I also understand this, because `char` can only store the first digit, in the form of a character, so anything after the first '6' during the input will be ignored.

```
char a; // combination 3
scanf("%c", &a); // suppose input is 65
printf("%c", a); // prints '6'
printf("%d", a); // prints 54 which is the ASCII value of '6'
```

But I have an issue with understanding what's happening here:

```
int a; // combination 4
scanf("%d", &a); // suppose input is 'A' (in fact any letter, upper or lower case)
printf("%c", a); // prints this symbol ╗
printf("%d", a); // prints 2
```

As mentioned its showing the same printf results regardless of which letters or upper/lower cases is being inputted. So I'm pretty confused!

I should also mention the reason I care about combination 4 is because I'm trying to define an `int` variable for `switch` which can compare cases of both letters and numbers, thus hoping to convert everything into `int` form. Using a `char` variable kind of works, but it's not ideal as it treats any 2-digit number the same as the first digit in that number.

**EDIT**: So I see that basically scanf does nothing in combination 4. What I'd like to know is a detailed explanation of why scanf can't be used this way when the other three combinations work.

Comment: scanf failed, it didn't read anything, check it's return value. `a` variable is uninitialized, scanf didn't touch it.

Comment: Check what [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) ***returns***! In the last case it should return `0` indicating that it didn't actually read and convert anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scanf a char using %d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44660548/scanf-a-char-using-d)

Comment: Sorry I'm new. How to check scanf returns? What exactly is the code? Below is my full code...

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{


int a;
scanf("%d", &a);
printf(" %c \n", a);
printf(" %d \n", a);

return 0;
}

Comment: `int i = scanf("%d", &a);` - Here check the value of `i` after the scan. In this case, it should return 1 for success and 0 for a fail.

Comment: If you had checked for errors on functions which return one as recommended, you wouldn't have had to ask.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, scanf skips reading Characters. run this simple test.

```
int a; // combination 4
scanf("%d", &a); // suppose input is 'A' (in fact any letter, upper or lower case)
if(scanf("%d", &a) == 1) //to check character read or not
    printf("input: %d\n", a);
else 
    printf("Character skipped");
printf("%c", a); // prints this symbol ╗
printf("%d", a); // prints 2
```

output: 
    Character skipped0

Comment: So I see that basically scanf does nothing in combination 4. What I'd like to know is a detailed explanation of why scanf can't be used this way when the other three combinations work.

Comment: by giving input as %d, you're defining it as a Single Decimal integer input. The range is -32768 to +32767. Large integers. A large integer is a binary integer with a precision of 31 bits. The range is -2147483648 to +2147483647.

So you can not give any input of a character while defining them as %d. Scanf checks against %d or %f or %c and so on... so you defining the variable as the character but calling the input method as an integer, which is a logical misunderstanding may be.

Comment: My confusion is why doesn't it convert 'A' to 65 and store it in `a` ? Because when you do `scanf("%c", &a)` and gives it a number it stores it fine. So the reverse of `scan("%d", &a)` and giving it a character should work? If doing so doesn't work, I'd like to know which function can allow that to work (ie. convert a character into its ASCII number).